# Camera chooserIntent not launch on Android M

Tags: android, android-camera

I have problem with pick Image From Galery and Camera Apps. I following [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/Mariovc/f06e70ebe8ca52fbbbe2) . The Problem is Camera chooserIntent not launch on Android M (other version is launch), but Galery intent is Launch. so how to fix it ?

this is chooserIntent :

```
public static Intent getPickImageIntent(Context context) {
        Intent chooserIntent = null;

        List<Intent> intentList = new ArrayList<>();

        Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        takePhotoIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(getTempFile(context)));
        intentList = addIntentsToList(context, intentList, pickIntent);
        intentList = addIntentsToList(context, intentList, takePhotoIntent);

        if (intentList.size() > 0) {
            chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intentList.remove(intentList.size() - 1),
                    context.getString(R.string.pick_image_intent_text));
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentList.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
        }

    return chooserIntent;
}
```

and implement code:

```
public class SimpleActivity {
  private static final int PICK_IMAGE_ID = 234; // the number doesn't matter

  public void onPickImage(View view) {
    Intent chooseImageIntent = ImagePicker.getPickImageIntent(this);
    startActivityForResult(chooseImageIntent, PICK_IMAGE_ID);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode) {
        case PICK_IMAGE_ID:
            Bitmap bitmap = ImagePicker.getImageFromResult(this, resultCode, data);
            // TODO use bitmap
            break;
        default:
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For open camera intent you can using it.

```
 static final int CAMERA_REQ_CODE = 1;

 Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

 fileUri = Uri.fromFile(yourFile);

 intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

 startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQ_CODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Runtime Permissions is only one problem. I was wondering why your app didn't crash when you didn't ask for CAMERA permission, and I figured it out. It's because you *never* open the camera:

```
chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intentList.remove(intentList.size() - 1),
                context.getString(R.string.pick_image_intent_text));
```

You removed the last intent in `intentList`, aka `takePhotoIntent`. So `intentList` contains only `pickIntent`. That's why.

---

Android M comes with [Runtime Permission](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). Some permissions need to be granted by user before app can use them. In this case, they're `CAMERA` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. So you must ask for permissions:

```
public void onPickImage(View view) {
    askForCameraPermission();
}

private void askForCameraPermission() {
    // Neither CAMERA or WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is granted
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

            // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Permissions needed");
            builder.setMessage("Some explanations");
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    // User understands the situation, now ask for permissions
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SimpleActivity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
                }
            });
            builder.show();

        } else {

            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }
    } else {

        // Permissions are already granted before
        Intent chooseImageIntent = ImagePicker.getPickImageIntent(this);
        startActivityForResult(chooseImageIntent, PICK_IMAGE_ID);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay!
                Intent chooseImageIntent = ImagePicker.getPickImageIntent(this);
                startActivityForResult(chooseImageIntent, PICK_IMAGE_ID);

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.

                // Blame user
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Error");
                builder.setMessage("Y u do dis?!");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Nah", null);
                builder.show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

Comment: Still not lauch camera :(

Answer (score 0):

With Android M there is a major change in Runtime Permissions. In order to use the camera you have to grant the permission in runtime. Take a look to this link, it explains how to handle permission request flow:

[New Android permissions](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en)